How can I add bottom text to a google maps pin with .NET 8 MAUI, or to make the label stay visible always?
I made a .NET 8 MAUI project for a mobile app, I got the map working and I have a list of icons that represent physical units that are tracked on the map, all of these icons must have a text with the unit id, however, when I create the the pins, the label property of the pins only appears when the specific pin is selected and disappears when not selected. The Pin class doesn't have a property to keep the labels visible
foreach (var element in CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(AppShell.ListaUnidades))
{
    var temp = new CustomPin()
    {
        Label = element.idtra,
        Location = new Location(Convert.ToDouble(element.paclat), Convert.ToDouble(element.paclon)),
        ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(ObtenerRumbo(element.pacrum) + element.Icono),
    };
    MapaUnidades.Pins.Add(temp);
}

Is there a way to keep the pin label visible? Or to maybe add some text below even if it isn't a part of the pin?
The customPin class extends Pin and has the ImageSource property added to change the pin icon image, I tried to go to the customMapHandler to change the markerOptions and keep the label visible, but it only has the option for the whole Pin visibility
foreach (var pin in mapPins)
{
    var pinHandler = pin.ToHandler(MauiContext);
    if (pinHandler is IMapPinHandler mapPinHandler)
    {
        var markerOption = mapPinHandler.PlatformView;
        if (pin is CustomPin cp)
        {
            cp.ImageSource.LoadImage(MauiContext, result =>
            {
                if (result?.Value is BitmapDrawable { Bitmap: not null } bitmapDrawable)
                {
                    markerOption.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBitmap(GetMaximumBitmap(bitmapDrawable.Bitmap, 100, 100)));
                }
                
                AddMarker(Map, pin, markerOption);
            });
            
        }
        else
        {
            AddMarker(Map, pin, markerOption);
        }
    }
}


As you said that the pin does not has the visible property. More information you can refer to this document Pin Class.
